# Детский вопрос о словах «книгОчей» и «казнАчей»

Tags: орфография, словообразование, устаревшие-слова

За неделю каникул пару раз с ребенком (10 лет) были в библиотеке. Знакомая работница назвала девочку *книг**о**чеем*. Не буду пересказывать вопросы и последующие рассуждения, но после приведенного мною примера (*казн**а**чей*) включилась детская логика:
— Книгочей *читает* книги. Казначей *считает*, хранит казну. А почему "а"?

Я порылась, нашла в ["Безбукв"](https://bezbukv.ru/mask/$%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9) еще два старых слова (*домр/ачей* и *собач/ей*) и совсем запуталась.
Книга, казна, домра... Понимаю, что слова старинные, но ведь интересно, почему в одном случае "чей" — это корень (книг/**о**/чей), а в другом "ачей" — суффикс (казн/**а**чей)?

Comment: Но: *казн**о**крад*. Так сложилось, не стоит искать какую-то логику.